# Can I use iframe on ADA compliant page?

Tags: html

I am making a non-secure page that has an iframe for a secure form. My concern is it ADA compliant? Does screen reader support iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I have found the answer for this. I don't want to delete it as it might be useful for other people with same question.

You can use an iframe and it can still be ADA compliant. I am saying it can be ADA compliant because the screen reader will be able to read through it.

Some screen reader tends not to load the iframe. So, it is always a best practice to write a message on the iframe that says 'You're browser doesn't support iframe and here's the link to the page that iframe is trying to load' or something like that. The trick is, even though the screen reader may not be able to read the iframe, it still can read the fall back text that has the link on it. The screen reader can follow the link and you'll get the intended content.